# Уникальные комбинации

Tags: комбинаторика, php

Дано n массивов например 3:
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

нужно получить все комбинации, элементов этих массивов

Comment: Ну что господа экстрасенсы, кто первый?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Dmitriy Farafontov](/users/10239/dmitriy-farafontov), представьте, что у вам даны дни, часы, минуты и секунды (четыре массива `[0..30],[0..23],[0..59],[0..59]`) и вам нужно пройти по каждой секунде. У вас получится цикл `31*24*60*60` итераций. На каждой итерации вам нужно будет определить номер дня, часа, номер минуты, номер секунды по номеру итерации. Например, итерация 1052200 дает 12 день 4 часа 16 минут 40 секунд (`12*24*60*60+4*60*60+16*60+40`). Таким образом, на каждой итерации вы получите уникальную комбинацию из четырех чисел (по количеству массивов).

Это называется система счисления с переменной базой.

[Вот](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanovsuper/fFnbs/) код на javascript'е для вашего примера. Для ваших массивов будет 48 итераций (`4*2*6`)...

Comment: отличное решение, а я рекурсии нагородил)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте вложенные циклы `foreach`, например 3.

Comment: а если, например, число массивов n, например, 100, то можно использовать, например, 100 вложенных циклов. да? ;)

Comment: я не знаю сколько у меня будет массивов